# How to create arguments in a custom bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Say I have something simple such as

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter process name to kill: ";

read -r process;

pgrep "$process" | xargs kill;
```

let's say this script has an alias of 'kp'

What do I have to do to remove `echo "Enter process name to kill: ";` and replace it with an argument that the command can take such as `kp firefox` rather than the input method.

Comment: Does this help? [Passing arguments to a script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152177/passing-arguments-to-a-script)

Comment: So do I need to remove $process and replace it with $1?

Comment: That should do it, yes

Comment: That worked. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

pgrep "$1" | sudo xargs kill;
```

Replacing $process with $1 and removing the input part did the trick. in the case above.